# Is there a better way to apply a filter over an Either right value?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Suppose you have an `IO (Either String (String, [Int]))` and you want to filter the `[Int]`.

Let's say we want to use the following filter:

```hs
:t filter even
Integral a => [a] -> [a]
```

As far as I understand we need to lift the function `filter even` to be applied to an `IO (Either String, (String, [Int]))`, so I did:

```hs
:t (fmap . fmap . fmap . filter) even
(Functor f1, Functor f2, Functor f3, Integral a) => f1 (f2 (f3 [a])) -> f1 (f2 (f3 [a]))
```

I know this symbol exists `<$$$>` (take a look [here](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%3C%24%24%24%3E&scope=set%3Astackage)), but I don't want to add that dependency.

Here is the full example:

```hs
--- You can paste this in GHCi
ioe = pure $ Right ("a,b,c,d", [1,2,3,4]) :: IO (Either String (String, [Int]))
(fmap . fmap . fmap . filter) even ioe
-- return: Right ("a,b,c,d",[2,4])
```

It works, but I wonder: is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `(fmap . fmap . fmap . filter) even` is certainly possible, there is a function for `Either` in `Control.Arrow` called `right`. The same module also contains `second`, which works on the second part of a pair.

```hs
right  :: (b -> c) -> Either a b -> Either a c`
second :: (b -> c) ->     (a, b) ->     (a, c)
```

The actual types use `Arrow` or `ArrowChoice`, but it basically boils down to this. With those functions, you can write `(fmap . fmap . fmap . filter) even ioe` as

```hs
(right . second . filter) even <$> ioe
-- or
(fmap . right . second . filter) even ioe
```

However, the behavior doesn't differ from your original variant.

Note that there are several libraries that provide lenses and enable you to write code in a similar way.